# onbeforeunload event message error in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, onbeforeunload

I use the following event to call when the application will close in Internet Explorer.It was work Fine that means it will call when i close IE browser Tab.And
    My problem is if I close the window I receive the message from Webpage,I receive the 'False'  statement with that message.If I remove the return false statement in this function  I didn't
    access the function.How to hide the False statement from the Msg Box?
    [image]

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) 
{

           if($.browser.msie)
           {
               alert('Test');
               return false;
            }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) 
{

           if($.browser.msie)
           {
               alert('Test');
               return "";
            }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Return Cusom Message instead of False

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) 
{   
return "Are you sure ";       
}
```

Comment: If i Use this i will get [object] instead of False

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of all major web browsers you cannot cancel a 'navigate away'. The only thing you can do is present the user with a message. This is accomplished by returning a string:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {return "your message goes here";}
```

The "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons as well as the surrounding text are controlled by the browser due to rampant abuse of this functionality in the early days of the internet. Don't even rely on your custom message being displayed. For example Firefox simply says that the page is trying to prevent you from navigating away but WILL NOT present your custom message.